# How can I mount a subdirectory from a hard drive to a separate directory

Tags: debian, fstab

I have this line in fstab

```
/dev/sda1 /Tera ntfs-3g uid=www-data,gid=www-data,umask=007 0 0
```

because /Tera/OC has to have permissions 770 but since the drive is NTFS, I can't set it explicitly. Is there a way for me to mount the folder OC on its own with the specified parameters and a different folder with different permissions? I considered splitting the partitions but I'd rather not divide the space.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your fstab:

```
/Tera/OC /mount/path/for/OC none bind,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,umask=770 0 0
```

Comment: @amjadkamali: For more information, `man 2 mount` and look for the bind option.

Comment: The binding worked but the man says data arguments are ignored (by the way, u/fmask permissions are opposite to the normal ones, 7=no access) Also found a workaround at https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/bind-mount-permissions-869332/